# Beacon Pairing iOS with only one UUID

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon, beacon

I'm working on my Beacon project and I'm looking for best way to solve my problem.

I have few central device declared as Beacon (not iBeacon UUID).
My iOS app is working as peripheral mode in Background and Foreground.

I would like send specific data (chain characters) to be written in my app during background and foreground work.

I know that UUID is hiden by iOS when app is in background. 
However, UUID is hiden only for devices which were not paired before.

Can i have a issue to implement list of UUID devices in my iOS list devices to be paired automatically when user downloaded the app ?

If not, Can I set one same UUID for my all central devices (but with with different minor and major values) and ask for first pairing when the app is turn as foreground for the first time with near central devices detected ?

Best regards,

Greg

Comment: You seem to have it backwards. Normally your peripheral would advertise a service with a known UUID and the central would be scanning for that service.

Comment: I am confused. Major and Minor numbers relate to IBeacons, not core bluetooth [although yes, they use BLE], but you say this isn't a iBeacon question? Besides which all iBeacons is advertise their presence.

Comment: Since you are not using standard iBeacon, but making custom beacons with CoreBluetooth, you need to describe how your beacons work (particularly with uuids) for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

My beacons are configured as central and they're scanning continually.

When they found iPhone's with my apps running as peripheral, my beacons try to write a value into my app.

I can't understand how implement my app (working as peripheral) to receive this value in background mode without pairing ?
--> Can I send value to my app without user pairing ?
If not
--> Can I send value to my app without user pairing including manually all my UUID's (central beacons) in the code of my app ?